# changing slurm bash script after submission (I want to change the script for a queuing job to avoid resubmission)

Tags: slurm, sbatch

I have submitted several bash scripts to slurm in a school cluster and there is a long queue. By some chance, I found I made a typo in one of my scripts in a dependence chain. If that is possible to modify the script without canceling the job and resubmission?